# Revert to stock Android email app?

Tags: email, gmail

I've long used the stock Android email app to remotely access my work Exchange email account.

With the latest update of the Gmail app, the Gmail app has taken over this email account, and launching the stock Android email app results in forwarding to the Gmail app.

I'd like to resume using the stock Android email app for this email account.  How can I do that?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only workaround for that would be to uninstall the most recent Gmail app and consider finding the previous update to it (ex, if it was 4.1.3, search Google for 4.1.2.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Removing the current version of Gmail had the useful effect of taking my Exchange account out of Gmail's account list, but the stock email app still points into Gmail!

Further, I can find no way to uninstall then reinstall the stock email app:  it's not in the list of installed apps that can be managed within Settings, and the only control in its Play Store entry is "Open," not "Install" or "Uninstall."

Any further thoughts?

Comment: Try installing the older 3.x instead of the 3.0.x (3 and x being hypothetical numbers of course).

Comment: Thanks again.  I ended up not having the patience, and installing a 3d party email app to handle my Exchange account (nine).

Comment: Well, I have had a good experience with K9 mail (in case you're looking for a good third-party app to handle your mail needs).